# How I get all Month From Date form sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have table names 'payroll' with following data

```
month , pay
January , 1200
March , 1500
December , 2000
```

I want the following result in crystal report from stored procedure i want a SQL query that Display this result

```
Janury , 1200
February , 000
March , 1500
April , 000
May , 000
June , 000
July , 000
August , 000
September , 000
October , 000
November , 000
December , 2000
```

Please help to make the query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not the work of your stored procedure. Fetch the data from sp and alter it as you require in your application. it is quite easy to do it in c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another table with all 12 months in it. Then perform a outer join with with `payroll` table.

Comment: Can U suggest Me any Another Way Of Doing This ??

Comment: No there is not other way to do it. Check the other answers. Everyone is creating a table somehow and joining it. I have told you the same thing already.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change your query -

```
SELECT [month], pay = ISNULL(pay, 0) 
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('January'),
        ('February'),
        ('March'),
        ('April'),
        ('May'),
        ('June'),
        ('July'),
        ('August'),
        ('September'),
        ('October'),
        ('November'),
        ('December')
) t([month])
LEFT JOIN <your_table> ON ....
```

Comment: `t` - alias for sub-query, `[month]` - column name

Answer (score 2):

In SQL server you can do like this:

```
WITH Months AS (
              SELECT 'January' AS MonthName
    UNION ALL SELECT 'February'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'March'  
    ...
)
SELECT Months.MonthName
      ,COALESCE(Payroll.Pay, 0)
FROM Months
     LEFT JOIN Payroll
         ON Months.MonthName = Payroll.Month
```

Answer (score 1):

You may neeed something like this.

```
declare @monthno int
declare @month varchar(50)

create table #month_tmp 
    ( mont varchar(20) null,number int null) 

set @monthno = 1
while @monthno < 13
begin
    SET @month=DateName(Month,cast(@monthno as varchar) + '-01-2001')

   insert into #month_tmp
    select @month, 0

    set @monthno = @monthno + 1
end

select [month],pay from payroll
union
select mont,number
from #month_tmp

drop table #month_tmp
```