# Grouping data with step down summation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with OrderDate,TotalAmount. I want to display month and TotalAmount of month with total amount of previous month to be added in next month.

e.g.

```
OrderDate    TotalAmount  
----------   -----------  
13.01.1998---     10  
15.01.1998---     11  
01.02.1998---     12  
18.02.1998---     10  
12.03.1998---     09
```

Output should be

```
Month     TotalSum  
------    --------  
1---           21  
2---           43  
3---           52
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/q/18651051/2445111

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: When you ask a sql query question specify what RDBMS you're using (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle...)

Comment: @Itay that question does not include running totals.

Comment: @AnandGupta check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver and my answer if performance matters for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data would only be from a single calendar year, you could use

```
with g as
( select month(orderdate) as ordermonth,
         sum( totalamount ) as sales
    from orders
    group by month(orderdate)
)
select m.ordermonth, sum(t.sales) as totalsales
  from g as m
  join g as t   on m.ordermonth >= t.ordermonth
  group by m.ordermonth
  order by m.ordermonth
```

But if there is ANY chance that your data could have two years, then you need year in there as well, so construct your month to include year.

```
with g as
( select format(orderdate, 'yyyy-MM') as ordermonth,
         sum( totalamount ) as sales
    from orders
    group by format(orderdate, 'yyyy-MM')
)
select m.ordermonth, sum(t.sales) as totalsales
  from g as m
  join g as t   on m.ordermonth >= t.ordermonth
  group by m.ordermonth
  order by m.ordermonth
```

Comment: Note: I work with DB2 for i, but instead gave you an answer that I believe should work on SQL Server.